# Remove project dependency when building framework/project

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks

I am working on a framework project where I have used some classes which my main application are already using. So If i made a build and integrate the framework into main project then we have duplicate code there.
For say ClassA and ClassB are used in both framework project and main project. In framework project I used another class ClassC where i access the functionalities of ClassA and ClassB and in main project I used ClassC(public header) from the framework project.

Is there any way to refer the ClassA and ClassB from the main project or remove dependency for those classes from framework project.

Thank you :)

Comment: I assume this has got nothing to do with Swift (as tagged)? Right?

Comment: yes, implementing in pure Objective C

Comment: Prefix you class names.